# How to show 3 parts in one single view in android tablet?

Tags: android

My application for android tablet contains 3 parts in one single view.

1. Listview items
2. On Click of list that contained in first part the second list items is shown in second part.
3. On Click of list that contained in second part the detils of each list should be shown in third part.

How to achieve this?Can Any anyone help me with some examples.

Answer (score 1):

add one ListView and two fragments into Activity . Both Fragments will have their own Life Cycle .

Comment: Can u provide me with some examples.i m confused with this fragments concept.